# How Do I Configure LAMP Server To Send Mail?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, sendmail, lamp

I'm currently running a LAMP server on Google VM. What is the cleanest and most efficient way to "send mail" from my website to my Gmail account using this configuration?

Comment: it's all in here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Comment: OK i installed SendGrid / PostFix ! I had previously crashed my server trying to configure php.ini ... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction